# Nokogiri not showing search-result

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Today I wanted to try out Nokogiri (Ruby) to list the addresses which are listed on this site: https://www.funda.nl/koop/rotterdam/straat-oostzeedijk/

I tried to show the addresses with the debugger using this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3CLEUBdWwQ

The results are

- Oostzeedijk 6 B01
- Oostzeedijk 166 C

It's class is called "search-result__header-title".

I tried different things such as div-elements but I can't show the results.

```
require 'nokogiri' 
require 'httparty' 
require 'byebug' 

def scraper
    url = "https://www.funda.nl/koop/rotterdam/straat-oostzeedijk/"
    unparsed_page = HTTParty.get(url)
    parsed_page = Nokogiri::HTML(unparsed_page)
    byebug 
end

scraper
```

In the debugger I have tried this:

```
(byebug) parsed_page
```

This give me a result, but when a specify this then the result is:

```
(byebug) parsed_page.css('div.search-content-output')    
[]
```

Can somebody give me a hint? I am stuck.

Comment: funda does not allow scraping [dutch link](https://twitter.com/funda/status/739818143112122368)

Comment: I recommend to also search for "Oostzeedijk beneden".

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that on the URL you are using (https://www.funda.nl/koop/rotterdam/straat-oostzeedijk/), content is loaded **asynchronously.**

The tutorial you're following assumes a "simple" web-page, where all of the page's content is loaded immediately. But for your scenario, `unparsed_page` is initially missing lots of page content that only loads later.

So what you need to do here is run code that actually mimics the behaviour of a user interacting with the website. There are many libraries designed to do this, so my solution below is certainly not the *only* option available, but hopefully you will find this concrete example useful.

I will be using Google Chrome, Chromedriver and the ruby library [watir](https://github.com/watir/watir). Prerequisites:

1. Install `chromedriver`. This step will vary depending on your operating system. For example, on MacOS, you can probably just run `brew install chromedriver`.
2. `gem install watir`

The code:

```
require 'watir'

b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto("https://www.funda.nl/koop/rotterdam/straat-oostzeedijk/")
puts b.div(class: 'search-content-output').text
```

Result:

> Hartschelp 111 Monster, € 1.395.000 k.k.
>
> Uitgelicht door Kolpa van der Hoek Makelaars Rotterdam
>
> Buitenbassinweg 506 Rotterdam, € 495.000 k.k.
>
> Uitgelicht door Oranje Bouwgroep B.V.
>
> Van der Duijn van Maasdamweg 614 O.3.6. Rotterdam, € 890.000 v.o.n.
>
> ...

Note that this website also seems to have a CAPTCHA to prevent web scrapers, however, the developers have screwed this up because the EU cookie consent popup appears *before* the CAPTCHA at the moment, thus rendering it somewhat useless